# Stop VS2010 from automatically attaching to browser process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm currently working on a web application in Visual Studio 2010. I prefer to debug the Javascript in this application using the development tools in IE, so every time I debug the app I have to manually detach the `iexplore.exe` process in the `Processes` window, so I can start debugging in IE.

This is a bit of an inconvenience, so I was wondering if it is possible to stop VS2010 from automatically attaching to the iexplore process when debugging? I have searched the net with no luck.

Comment: 1 way to do it is to use another browser (let's say chrome) by default. But if your goal is to use the IE Javascript console, then I guess it won't make it for you!

Comment: Hmm yeah, I tried that, but having to manually open the URL in IE after VS automatically opens Chrome is equally inconvenient. :/

Thanks for the tip, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just JavaScript that you want to debug then you can start your Web application without debugging via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. This will avoid the "Unable to attach to the process. Another debugger might be attached to the process." error.

To debug both server-side and client-side code at the same time I normally just use a different browser, as @cheesemacfly wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this a bit in the past when I was debugging a specific Javascript issue, but I'm doing quite a lot of ajax work and would ideally like to debug the code in my handlers as well

Comment: Set as answer as it appears that the functionality I want doesn't exist, and this is the best workaround.